# Rename computer name with .NET

Tags: c#, wmi

I am trying to rename a computer name from a C# application.

```
public class ComputerSystem : IComputerSystem
{
    private readonly ManagementObject computerSystemObject;

    public ComputerSystem()
    {
        var computerPath = string.Format("Win32_ComputerSystem.Name='{0}'", Environment.MachineName);
        computerSystemObject = new ManagementObject(new ManagementPath(computerPath));
    }

    public bool Rename(string newComputerName)
    {
        var result = false;

        var renameParameters = computerSystemObject.GetMethodParameters("Rename");
        renameParameters["Name"] = newComputerName;

        var output = computerSystemObject.InvokeMethod("Rename", renameParameters, null);

        if (output != null)
        {
            var returnValue = (uint)Convert.ChangeType(output.Properties["ReturnValue"].Value, typeof(uint));
            result = returnValue == 0;
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

The WMI call returns error code 1355.

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393056%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) doesn't mention much about error codes, what does it mean and how can I fix it?

Comment: Is the computer you're tring to rename in an Active Directory environment?

Comment: This *may* be of some interest to you: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/219c4b4b-b43a-4dbc-9e3c-a1135879c5f9/information-about-the-domain-could-not-be-retrieved-1355?forum=netfxbcl

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Error code 1355](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681385%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) means `ERROR_NO_SUCH_DOMAIN`: *"The specified domain either does not exist or could not be contacted."*.

The [documentation for the Rename method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393056%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) states that the name **must** contain the domain name. For a non-domain-joined machine, try `.\NewName` instead of just `NewName`.

Comment: Thanks for the link to system errors! Bookmarked it, that'll be helpful the coming days. And thanks for solving my problem too (I am testing on a domain PC, but the program will run on non-domain PCs in the end, I'll figure something out)